# google colab OS errors

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am getting 'OS error: Transport endpoint not connected' on colab notebook, while running MD simulations through Amber. Is it because of low computing units? How do i fix it? I have attached a picture for reference.

not tried anything yet [OS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTnD1.jpg)